# websocket messeges conjunction

Tags: node.js, linux, websocket, vps

Today, when I try to deploy my project to linux-based vps (azure and ec2) I had problem: messages sending with 30ms interval, but often arrive to server "In packages"(with 0-1ms interval between messages) of 5 messages. But when I start my nodejs server on my windows-based PC there no problems.
Thanks.
Info: Libraries: express,ws; To run:npm start

Comment: Hi, What technology is your project ? What steps you followed to deploy it, the scripts that you ran. And then the error that you saw on running the scripts. That way it's helpful for someone to see what is there and ask questions (or) give answers. Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On  linux machine you must set perMessageDeflate:false